# Provisioning Profile for app disappeared? Failed to code sign

Tags: ios, xcode

When I try to run my app that's been working fine for months on my iPhone (although it works fine on the simulator) I now get `Failed to code sign "<My App>"`. and I get an option to Fix Issue, but that fails and leads to this message: `An App ID with Identifier '<My App>.<My App>' is not available. Please enter a different string.` I'm working with a partner over github and I pushed the code to him, it popped up and he selected his personal Development Team and it fixed the issue, instead of telling him `...<My App>.<My App> is not available ...`.

When I told him to go to Preferences > Accounts > View Details, he has a Provisioning Profile for `<My App>.<My App>` whereas I don't, and presumably it disappeared somehow and this is the cause of my problem. I don't know how to fix this tho. I recently applied to an organization Apple dev account but that's still in the process of being enrolled, but that's the only thing I can think of that would have broken this.

I've gone thru a bunch of answers on SOF and no matter what I do I always end up with the error: `No matching provisioning profiles found: No provisioning profiles with a valid signing identity (i.e. certificate and private key pair) matching the bundle identifier “<My App>.<My App>” were found.` Really stumped on how to fix this

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to go into the Apple Developer Portal and either create new provisioning profiles or download the existing certificates to be installed into your keychain access.

Comment: how do I do that? Every time go to https://developer.apple.com/account/ it just redirects me to https://developer.apple.com/account/#/welcome and all I see is a welcome screen with Download Tools, Build Your First App, and Join the Apple Developer Program, it looks nothing what the Apple docs show: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingProfiles/MaintainingProfiles.html

Comment: Could you attached a screenshot and are you a registered Apple Developer?  Also it sounds like you all will need to add your device so that it recognizes your UID when compiling on the device.